# woocommerce conditional field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I can not figure out how to activate the function when the user selects a field in the woocommerce checkout, this is my code, 
I want it to be active only when the user selects 1 in the checkout selection fields

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','conditional_add_fee' );
function conditional_add_fee() {
     global $woocommerce;

     if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
          return;
     $subtotal = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal;
     $fee_percentage = 0.22; // 22 percent
     $fee = number_format( round( $subtotal * $fee_percentage, 2 ), 2 ); // rounded to two decimal places to match currency formatting
     $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'IVA', $fee, true, 'standard' );
}
```

thanks

Comment: What functionality you are trying to achieve?

Comment: in woocommerce checkout I entered fields, if a field is selected, it must apply the condition